# Can I filter the Suggested Edits queue to exclude tag wikis?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Approving an edit of a tag-wiki requires quite a lot of knowledge. Is what's written there correct and relevant? Was it pasted from Wikipedia? Does it help to distinguish between related similar tags? If you don't know the subject matter well, you can't do a good job of it. I skip essentially all tag-wiki suggested edits.

Ordinary edit suggestions need very different approval decisions. I skip almost none of them. Occasionally someone will replace a dead link or something like that and I don't feel like doing the extra work to confirm the old link was dead and the new link is about whatever the post says its about.

If I could filter the Suggested Edits queue to exclude tag wikis, I would be a happier camper. Can it be done?

Comment: Please don't! If you're concerned you're more likely to attempt to understand what's going on and thereby allow better edits then serial approvers.

Comment: Most of the tag wiki edits are text lifted from somewhere - if we reject then no content, but no one actually bother to write it in the first place anyway (if it is some unpopular tag).

Comment: I came searching for this for exactly the same reason.  Additionally, I think that being able to filter based on the type of edit would be a nice parallel to the way that we can filter items in the close votes by reason (duplicate, off-topic, &c.).