# Oh my.. there's a [system] tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we burninate [system]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152366/should-we-burninate-system)

How the heck did [system](/questions/tagged/system) ever come to be? I just rejected a possible tag wiki for it (hey it turns out [I can have an opinion on tag wikis after all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152209/can-i-filter-the-suggested-edits-queue-to-exclude-tag-wikis)!) and discovered to my dismay it has over 1500 questions. At first glance not one of them is improved by having this tag. I would like to suggest it simply be ripped away from every question that sports it.