# Proposed tag wiki edit - no review yet

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, stackapps

I suggested a [tag wiki edit](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/1368) **two days ago**. However, there has not been any review yet.

The original wiki is from **Feb 2011**. Now I'm wondering whether in the span of almost 3.5 years:

- Has *anyone* suggested edits to the same tag before me (that are not approved yet)?
- Are there many suggested edits by others *on that same tag* waiting in queue?
- Is anyone looking at the tag wiki proposed edit queue in **Stack Apps**? *(But I guess there is no separate queue for it, [according to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165254).)*

> **Dear Overlords,**
>   If you will kindly review it, please note that this humble servant has mainly added a note about the new enhancement in *Google Chrome,* in addition to other improvements to the wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, there **had** not been any review yet.

"had" being the imperative word now, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)*.

<sub>*strictly speaking you *can* still use method two, but it requires enabling developer mode, which may or may not be a good suggestion for the average user</sub>

Comment: Huh? What does grammar have to do with the status?

Comment: I was just indicating that I've now reviewed (and approved) it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I edited it to "has".

Comment: Oh, you didn't have to - I wasn't trying to imply anything was wrong with the question, just being "clever" in my reply. :)

Comment: Even developer mode doesn't work permanently because as soon as you restart Chrome, the developer extensions are booted out.

Comment: Huh, I don't have that problem, at least with userscripts.

Comment: Oh, IDK, it's things I read. It's a big mess since Chrome 35. Everyone's royally pissed. *"just being "clever" in my reply."* LOL... I thought you were bullying me by picking on my bad grammar!! I didn't understand that you were trying to tell me that you completed the review!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of those changes either. They claim it's for "user safety", but it has the convenient side effect of corralling everyone into the Chrome Web Store. Clearly I failed at being clever, I admit ;) Sorry about that!

Comment: No worries. Love your profile picture. Very creative!

Answer (score 4):

> •Has anyone suggested edits to the same tag before me?

The [revision history](https://stackapps.com/posts/2059/revisions) of that tag says that eight of the sixteen prior revisions were suggested, rather than being made outright. This includes [the most recent revision](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/1162).

> •Are there many suggested edits by others on that same tag waiting in queue?

If there were, you'd have gotten an error message when you tried to make your suggestion.

> •Is anyone looking at the tag wiki proposed edit queue in Stack Apps? (But I guess there is no separate queue for it, according to this.)

StackApps is small. A quick check of the [users list](https://stackapps.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) shows only five non-moderators have the 5K rep needed for the [Approve Tag Wiki Edits privilege](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). Give it some time, and I'm sure someone'll be along eventually to take a look at it.

Comment: Actually for the first question, I meant to ask if anyone suggested an edit that is still pending review (which is what I wanted quantified in the second question). Anyway thank you for your insights. I hope you're right about the error message as I'm not exactly sure if that's applicable to tag wiki edits.