# Lower the rep requirement for tag wiki edits

Tags: feature-request, tags, privileges, private-beta

I have been in multiple new (private) betas where the tag wiki edit queues are reviewed so infrequently that many users like me appear to rarely even bother with them, because half the time important tags are blocked pending another edit approval, and otherwise it could be a week before any content added is actually seen.

This is a problem because it's the new betas where clarification of rapidly proliferating tags is most important.

I don't see any reason why tag wikis should be more sensitive than Q&As, so why not do one or more of the following:

1. Give the tag wiki edit permission to the top *n* users
2. Give tag wiki edit permission at the same thresholds where edit permissions are given (presently 500 rep in early beta)
3. Setup a tag review queue that is open to most users in early beta like the other review queues are
4. <s>Include</s> Show tag edits in the Suggested Edits review queue for more users (see comments)

Comment: Tag wiki edits do appear in the suggested edits queue. The easiest thing to do would be to lower the reputation threshold for the explicit [approve tag wiki edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege, which is currently set to 750 for private betas.

Comment: So does the content of the Suggested Edits queue vary by user privilege?  E.g., users won't see suggested tag edits in there until they have the privilege, even though they see the queue?

Comment: Exactly right. Although currently a tag wiki edit is the only other type of edit suggestion you could get in that queue.

Comment: Related to #3: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165254/create-a-separate-review-queue-for-tag-wiki-edits