# I don't understand most tag wiki edits in review queue

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I skip through most tag wiki edits because I have no clue about the topic. I would need to google it up and verify all the information and that's simply more work than I am about to invest into review queue. Some edits fix a broken link - even this requires me to check both links to see if it's not spam/advertisement.

I don't think tag wiki edits belong in suggested edits queue at all. They require different knowledge, different skills, have different UI.

I want to hear what you think - am I just too lazy? Or does it sound like tag wiki reviews take me longer than they should?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152209/can-i-filter-the-suggested-edits-queue-to-exclude-tag-wikis

Answer (score 8):

First: thank you for being a *good* reviewer; far too many people just approve these without doing nearly the amount of research you describe here.

I generally have the same problem - I'm not an expert in everything (it's actually far closer to nothing). That said, I would vote for these to stay in the suggested edit queue, possibly with improved guidance encouraging skipping then if you're not an expert in that tag.

That's what I usually do: If I don't consider myself an expert in the tag, and the suggestion changes actual content (is not just a simple grammar/spelling fix or similar), I nearly always skip it.

Given this, I'd propose we fix this by simply **weighting them to be shown near the bottom of the queue** if a user doesn't have *x* answers/upvotes in the tag. This would keep the ability to suggest edits, in a queue that already exists, but without wasting your and my time on edits that we probably can't do a good job reviewing.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, that's great idea. Also because edits on posts are often blocking other editors, tags are not so exposed.